# Windows 8, 8.1, 2012 R2: Search does not work correctly after joining local AD domain

Tags: windows-8.1, search, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

Scenario:
I do a fresh install of e.g. Windows 8.1 on a workstation.
Then I create a temporary local user on this system -> searching in the start menu for e.g. "programs and features" (German: "Programme und Features") works without a problem.

Then I join my local Active Directory domain, and from this point, when I log in as a domain user, the search does not find items any more which reside in the Control Panel (e.g. it does not find programs and features, but it does find scheduled tasks).

I tried it with several 2003 R2, 2008 R2 and 2012 R2 domain controllers, it is always the same behavior.
Modifying Indexing options also did not have any effect.
It does not matter if the user has Admin permissions or default.

Is there maybe some GPO setting I have to change?

Windows 7 start menu search always worked fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out I simply did not wait long enough.
It seems like after joining the domain the search function is not as fast as before. It takes 4 - 6 seconds to find more items and you don't see that the searching process has not finished yet.

Anyway, it's a bit strange that I cannot find items like "computer management" any more, but the rest works.